# Get json array value from observable and give data to frontend

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, json-server

Trying get JSON array from json-server using observables and then giving the value to frontend and perform search on the JSON array received through observable

created a service and used HTTP get to connect to server and subscribed to it
created for loop to get value from returned value of subscription

```js
**service.ts**
export class FormdtService {
  baseul='http://localhost:3000/objects'//jsonserver url
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getdt():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseul)
  }
}

**component.ts**
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public fbu:FormBuilder,private fdts:FormdtService) {}
  //creates the reactive form
 form=this.fbu.group({
    un:'',
    id:''
   })
 //  baseul='http://localhost:3000/objects/';
//ngsubmit control of form brings this function
  ser(){
    this.fdts.getdt().subscribe(dt=>{
      console.log("data: "+dt[0])
      this.formdt.push(dt)
      //console.log("formdt :"+this.formdt[0])
    for (let ite in this.formdt){
      let ite1=JSON.parse(ite)
     // console.log("ite :"+this.formdt[ite]);
      //console.log("ite1"+ite1);
      this.idlist.push(ite1.person.bioguideid.value)
if(ite1.person.bioguideid.stringify==this.idsearch)
this.objson=ite1
    }});
  }
idsearch:string
formdt:string[]
idlist:string[]
objson:JSON
  ngOnInit() {

  }
 //this function is attached to button in frontend
 ser(){
    this.fdts.getdt().subscribe(dt=>
this.formdt.push(dt)//subscribes to service
    for (let ite in this.formdt){
      let ite1=JSON.parse(ite)
      this.idlist.push(ite1.person.bioguideid.value)
if(ite1.person.bioguideid.value==this.idsearch)
this.objson=ite1
  })}
```

```
**json**
[
  {
    "caucus": null,
    "congress_numbers": [
      114,
      115,
      116
    ],
    "current": true,
    "description": "Senior Senator for Tennessee",
    "district": null,
    "enddate": "2021-01-03",
    "extra": {
      "address": "455 Dirksen Senate Office Building Washington DC 20510",
      "contact_form": "http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email",
      "fax": "202-228-3398",
      "office": "455 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
      "rss_url": "http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=rss.feed"
    },
    "leadership_title": null,
    "party": "Republican",
    "person": {
      "bioguideid": "A000360",
      "birthday": "1940-07-03",
      "cspanid": 5,
      "firstname": "Lamar",
      "gender": "male",
      "gender_label": "Male",
      "lastname": "Alexander",
      "link": "https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/lamar_alexander/300002",
      "middlename": "",
      "name": "Sen. Lamar Alexander [R-TN]",
      "namemod": "",
      "nickname": "",
      "osid": "N00009888",
      "pvsid": "15691",
      "sortname": "Alexander, Lamar (Sen.) [R-TN]",
      "twitterid": "SenAlexander",
      "youtubeid": "lamaralexander"
    },
    "phone": "202-224-4944",
    "role_type": "senator",
    "role_type_label": "Senator",
    "senator_class": "class2",
    "senator_class_label": "Class 2",
    "senator_rank": "senior",
    "senator_rank_label": "Senior",
    "startdate": "2015-01-06",
    "state": "TN",
    "title": "Sen.",
    "title_long": "Senator",
    "website": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public"
  },//end of single json array object
  {
    "caucus": null,
    "congress_numbers": [
      114,
      115,
      116
    ],  
"current": true,
    "description": "Senior Senator for Maine",
    "district": null,....same repetition of structure
```

The ser function should give whole JSON array present in server to formdt[] and then iterate over it and get every object and convert to JSON and push bioguide to id array,search id from input and match with JSON nested value of each object in the array
nothing happens gives error in console :

**_this.formdt is undefined at line 37 `(this.fdts.getdt().subscribe(dt=>this.formdt.push=dt))`**

Comment: I don't see where `formdt` is initialized. You just declare it as an `string[]`, but you should actually asign it to an array: `formdt: string[] = []`. You will probably have to do the same with your other instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Given error is pretty explicit : `this.formdt` is undefined.

You've declared preperty type but haven't initialize it.

So replace `formdt:string[]` with `formdt:string[] = []`

Comment: that error was gone thanks but another error ite1.person is undefined happened and using console.log to check values of dt or ite showing [object Object] for dt and ite has numeric index of for loop